# np.logical_or with reduce return a different result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`np.logical_or` with `functools.reduce` returns a different result.

```
kdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : [' False', 1, np.nan], 'dt': [datetime.now(), ' 2018-12-12', '2019-12-12'], 'bool': 
                         [False, True, True], 'i': [1,2,'3'], 'bnan': [False, True, np.nan], 'col2': [' True ', False, 'False']})

print([kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F') for i in ['col1', 'col2']])

# [0    True
# 1     NaN
# 2     NaN
# Name: col1, dtype: object, 0    False
# 1      NaN
# 2     True
# Name: col2, dtype: object]
```

you could see this returns the expected output but when we reduse this with `np.logical_or`, it returns `Nan` for third row instead of `True`

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.logical_or, [kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F') for i in ['col1', 'col2']])

# 0    True
# 1     NaN
# 2     NaN
# dtype: object
```

But `np.logical_or(np.nan, True)` returns `True`. I hope the reduce would apply the function to all the list items ie,

```
kdf['col1'].str.contains('^\s*F') | kdf['col2'].str.contains('^\s*F')
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is bug, for correct processing with NaNs should be replace them to some boolean , e.g. to `False` by `na=False` parameter:

```
from functools import reduce
a = reduce(np.logical_or, [kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F') for i in ['col1', 'col2']])
print (a)
0    True
1     NaN
2     NaN
dtype: object

b = np.logical_or.reduce([kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F') for i in ['col1', 'col2']])
print (b)
[True nan nan]

c = kdf['col1'].str.contains('^\s*F') | kdf['col2'].str.contains('^\s*F')
print (c)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
from functools import reduce
a = reduce(np.logical_or, [kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F', na=False) for i in ['col1', 'col2']])
print (a)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

b = np.logical_or.reduce([kdf[i].str.contains('^\s*F', na=False) for i in ['col1', 'col2']])
print (b)
[ True False  True]

c = kdf['col1'].str.contains('^\s*F', na=False) | kdf['col2'].str.contains('^\s*F', na=False)
print (c)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: `s = pd.Series([1, True, False], name='bool'); s.isin([True])`, returns `True`, `True`, 'False', can we do a strict match? ie. I don't want pandas to return `True` for 1

Comment: @AvinashRaj - possible, but not so nice `print ((s == True) & s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool)))
print (s.isin([True]) & s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool)))
`

Comment: does it would be consider slower? I want all the rows having anyone of the column contain (~bool). So if I do compare `col1`, `col2`, it has to rwturn all the 3 rows since no row contain bool value in both the columns

Comment: done `kdf[np.logical_and.reduce([kdf[i].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool)) for i in ['col1', 'col2']]) == False]`